# Take input of arbitrary size in theano

Tags: python-2.7, theano

I built a cnn network in Theano. Input are many images, but the size of them are different. The elements of numpy.array have the same size.
How can I make them as the input?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some data formatting. The input size of a NN is constant, so if the images for your CNN have different sizes you need to resize them to your input size before feeding them in. Its like a person being too close or far away from a painting, your field of view is contant, in order to see everything clearly you need to adjust your distance from the image.

Answer (score 0):

When training your network, for architectural and performance reasons, all your input images should be of the same shape, usually square. You can achieve square input e.g. by doing

1. reshape the image such that the smaller side is equal to the square sidelength, while preserving aspect ratio
2. crop the image along the other axis, either in the middle or in a random location, to obtain the square

This makes sure that the image is not distorted.

That said, if you have already trained your network, and would like to apply it to an image bigger than its normal input size, then you can convolve the convnet over the image. This is explained in Pierre Sermanet's OverFeat paper. It is also implemented for the estimators in sklearn-theano at http://sklearn-theano.github.io